# Contains() and Replace() work in console but not when running script

Tags: powershell

I have an XML file that I open and store in a string with `Get-Content` and I need to perform a series of `Replace()` operations to fill in some of the empty elements.

I'm copying the substrings I need to replace directly from the XML file into the script, and all but one perform the replace. Using `Contains()` on the substring also returns `False`.

If I open the XML file using the command line and try and perform the same replace, copied directly from the script, it works and using `Contains()` returns `True`.

I thought it might have been the order in which the `Replace()` methods run, but I've rearranged the order and it still doesn't work. I also thought it might have been some whitespace, but every other substring I'm replacing has some whitespace in it too.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this disparity?

EDIT:

Code example:

```
$sharedStrings = '.\sharedStrings.xml'
$feeInfo = @('100.00', 'Cheque')

$excelXml = Get-Content -Path $sharedStrings -Encoding UTF8

$excelXml = $excelXml.Replace('Fee Due:       £', "Fee Due:       £$($feeInfo[0])")
$excelXml = $excelXml.Replace('Expected By:  Cheque  /  Card   /   On-Line', "Expected By:  $($feeInfo[1])")

$excelXml | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 ".\output.xml"
```

Sample of input XML:

```
<t xml:space="preserve">Fee Due:       £                               Expected By:  Cheque  /  Card   /   On-Line                             Paid on:                 /               /                                  </t>
```

Sample of output XML:

```
<t xml:space="preserve">Fee Due:       £                               Expected By:  Cheque                             Paid on:                 /               /                                  </t>
```

Comment: When the Contains() throws out `false` my first guess would be to check if the variables deliver the right output when you run the script, just echo out the Output on Script and check it.

Comment: Please supply and minimal, verifiable, complete example. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more information about echoing output and some examples of the functions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code and sample input.

Comment: Share the piece of XML as well as share the Code to understand better .

Comment: I've shared the important parts of the XML and a proper example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this doesn't answer completely what is happening since I do not fully understand how character encoding works in Powershell when files are read and written vs. executing scripts.

However, the problem is that when the input file is read the pound sign becomes a two byte character ('Â£') in the string. The Replace function cannot match the 'Â£' with '£' and the replacement fails.
I cannot provide a true solution but a workaround for this. Use the -replace operator instead of the .Replace function since -replace can handle regular expressions.

The following line works:

```
($excelXml -replace '(Fee Due: +.)', "`$1|$($feeInfo[0])").Replace('|', '')
```

The reason for having the '|' in here is that I cannot figure out how to get the `$1$($feeInfo[0])`sequence to work. `$1`followed by a `$` doesn't work in a double quoted string.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still not sure where the encoding error happened, but I ended up using the explicit unicode for `£` in place of your solution.

`$excelXml = $excelXml.Replace("Fee Due:       $([char]0x00A3", "Fee Due:       $([char]0x00A3)$($feeInfo[0])")`

Comment: Yes, even better! My solution wasn't the most elegant :)